# Entity fetched from a webservice: how to integrate in DDD model?

Tags: web-services, service, domain-driven-design, entity, soa

I have a "Process" application with a complex model (simplified here). The application has a webservice as such:

```
Webservice             | Application behind webservice
------------------------------------------------------
ProcessDTO             | Process
    .getLabel()        |     .getLabel()
                       |     .getSubComponents()
                       |     .execute(input) // calls ProcessComponent.execute
                       | ProcessComponent
                       |     .execute(input)
ProcessService         | ProcessRepository
    .findProcess(id)   |     .findProcess(id)
    .executeProcess(..)|
```

The problem is: **how do I integrate `Process` entities inside an application using this webservice?**

---

I was thinking of creating a `Process` entity instead of directly using the DTO as an entity.

For example, in another application, I have `Module` that has a `Process`.

I can hook up in my ORM so the "association" part is not a problem. The problem is **how `Module` executes a Process?**

- by calling the `ProcessService`: that's ugly because I'll end up with an anemic Process entity that doesn't offer any domain logic. Furthermore, that will make the `Module` entity use a service, which is not so good right?
- by adding an `execute()` method in `Process`? But then the entity method also calls a service which is not good

Answer (score 1):

In DDD, external web services should be encapsulated by an [anti-corruption layer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AnticorruptionLayer) (ACL). In the ACL, the DTO contracts of the web service should be mapped to locally defined value objects.

As far as calling the external service, that should be done by the [application service](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) hosting the corresponding use case, not by the entities as you observed.

Comment: "DTO should be mapped to VO" > I am mapping to an entity: I don't see how a `Process` with an identity could be a VO? What am I missing?

Comment: And I don't see the problem of having an interface for the `ProcessService` in the domain layer, implemented in the architecture layer by a service that hits the webservice? And how would you do with my problem given what you said? I can't imagine a solution.

Comment: You can map to an entity as well, however remember that an entity has identity is persistent. Will the external DTOs be persisted as local entities? If so, then you can map to an entity. Otherwise, mapping to a transient entity doesn't make sense. Indeed there is no problem in calling an interface encapsulating the process service. What I'm saying is that an application service which implements use cases which require calls to the external services should call the service, not any entities.